# Unity how to set the radius of a sphere in global scale?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the sphere is a child, it inherits the scale of its parent. The spheres always become the ellipsoids. Is there a way to set the radius of that sphere to be a certain number no matter what its parent's scales are?

Comment: Are there rotations in the ancestor transforms?

Comment: there is a rotation of 90 degrees on the z-axis

Comment: please [include the hierarchy in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62670574/edit) also showing which gameobject is the sphere and which gameobjects have rotations and scales on their transforms

Answer (score 1):

If none of the ancestors are rotated, there's a simple solution:

Set the local scale to be the reciprocol of the parent's [`lossyScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html). Putting it in `LateUpdate` will guarantee that its scale is set after any of its ancestors' `Update` methods change its scale. If the ancestors' scales change in any of their `LateUpdate`s, you might want to look into [Script Execution Order Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) to set the sphere's script to execute last.

For instance:

```
public void LateUpdate(){
    Vector3 parentScale = transform.parent.lossyScale;
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f/parentScale.x, 1f/parentScale.y, 
            1f/parentScale.z);
}
```

Comment: It's still an ellipsoid